# Data Subscriptions in Infux V2.X

Tags: influxdb, influxdb-2, flux-influxdb

In Influx V1.8 there are subscriptions, that are sending all the data to a specified target.

I want to send all the incoming Data to an Azure Event-Hub. Subscriptions in V1.8 worked great for this, but i don't know how to do it in Influx V2.6, as there are no longer Subscriptions to use.
How do i get this result in an InfluxDB V2.6?

I already looked into the documentation, but i can just find information about the influx V1.8.

I tried to it with Telegraph, but i was not able to do it, because i don't know that input plugin i should use for this.